# Access url path inside *ngIf

Tags: angular, angular-router

I need to access the path of my url within a `*ngIf`. I've tried the following:

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    providers: [],
    templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(public route: ActivatedRoute) {

    }
}
```

And in my HTML/Pug:

```
div(*ngIf='route.firstChild?.url?.value[1]?.path == "somePath"')
```

It does work when I build it using angular cli but when I try to build it with aot, I get the following error: `Property 'value' does not exist on type 'Observable<UrlSegment[]>'`

Seems like I'm not allowed to directly access the value of an observable inside `*ngIf`

Comment: I would say put the url in a variable and use that in your view

Comment: I thought about it... the problem is that my route doesn't always have a first child.

Comment: I could listen to a route change and subscribe to the url if first child exists...but it seems very complicated for what I want to achieve. Hope there is a cleaner solution

Comment: try to use async pipe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that you can't directly access the value of the observable, it's that the value of the observable is undefined when the browser initializes the view. This is in general how Observables work since they are asynchronous in nature.

Two ways I can think of to solve this:

1. Use Angular 2's async pipe: https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe. This will allow the view to wait for the next value provided by the observable, and AOT shouldn't complain.
2. Subscribe to the value of the route either in your constructor or in an ngOnInit lifecycle hook, assign that value to a variable in your component class, and use that component-binded variable in your ngIf statement (make sure your initialize the variable to false if you go this route or AOT may complain that the value is undefined)

Comment: Option 1 seems to be what I'd like to do but I can't figure out how to do it... what does async return? Do you have an example?

Comment: It returns the onNext value of the observable. It's pretty much the same as option 2 except you use `| async` instead of subscribe. Once you get the hang of it you'll be using `| async` everywhere! (not sure if that's recommended though)